# Angular service worker not register in development mode

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I would like to know if it' s possible to test pwa and register the serviceworker during the dev mode ( not production)

As when i make the ng build --prod then launchhttp-server in the dist folder it works fine, but then when i do ng serve without the build it gives me the chrome error: Service Worker failed to register

Are the procedures same on prod and dev ? as with lighthouse, the audit gives me ok on serviceworker on prod but not in dev for the same project

Any helps or links would be appreciate

Thanks

Comment: Could you please check the documentation https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

Comment: Hi Nour, that' s exactly what i did, but that' s means that i have everytime for changes make another ng build --prod and go to the dist to launch the http-server  ? i dev without the build on the http://localhost:4200/ port

Comment: because what i did before is to launch ng serve from my app root folder without a build, which is really convienient, moreover i got the error message on the codes   providers: [
    CheckForUpdateService,
    LogUpdateService,
    PromptUpdateService,
  ], ==> cannot find nemaes for them

Comment: Actually i did not use service worker with angular before, but as i can see the documentation mentioned that you can determine what is the environment you want to use service worker. `ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', {enabled: environment.production})`

Comment: the definition of the environment is basic: export const environment = {
  production: false
}; no much dev environment :(

Comment: I am also having this problem. you can ```ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', {enabled:true})``` but there is no ngsw-worker.js generated

Answer (score 4):

This question is 2 years old but I see it wasn't answered.

You cannot run service worker with ng server.  As you mentioned, it works using http-server.   This is by design.  See Angular documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started).

However, if you are not testing specific service worker functionality, such as retrieving data from cache if offline, your application will still function using ng serve, including retrieving data via http.

Answer (score 2):

Facing the same issue recently.
As mentioned, there is a parameter to enable the service worker for certain environment which by default is set to production only?

The solution was to remove the default `enabled` setting in the ServiceWorkerModule registration to have it run regardless of the environment

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [AppComponent],
imports: [
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
        // Remove the following line to enable the service worker for development
        // enabled: environment.production,
        registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
    })
]
})
```

[As of Angular 14.2, ng serve also supports service worker](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9869). So potentially you no longer need to rely on http-server to test your web app.